# Can a Flood Element script interact with the Shadow DOM (or even the DOM) directly or throuth browser object?

Tags: node.js, playwright, flood-element

I'm using Flood Element 2.0 and using a very basic script to test a Login page.  The Username and Password fields are contained inside the #shadow-root, and all of my attempts to get a handle for those elements have failed, so far.  I just get timeouts.

Playwright itself finds the elements and types text into them, no problem.  Flood Element does not, though it is "built on Playwright."

Is there any way in Flood Element scripts to access the shadow-root of an element?

Here's an excerpt from my DOM: [#shadow-root of login component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMuVX.png)